# app-bar has padding although i made its width to" match_parent" in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I make the width of the app-bar = "match_parent" but it still has top , right and left padding

in app_bar layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ..."
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFEB3B"/>
```

in styles.xml :

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

in MainActivity

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Comment: can you show a little more xml code? Maybe the root layout has padding which contains the `Toolbar`

Comment: You are right ,thank you